# Update real time d3 chart by socket.io

Tags: angularjs, node.js, d3.js, socket.io, directive

I am writing a d3.js-based real time chart directive. The structure looks like this:

**myDirective.js**:

```
app.directive('myDirective', function(socketio) {

  return {
    restrict: 'EA',
    templateUrl: '../../views/partials/chart.html',
    controller: DataController,

    link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {

      scope.Watch = scope.$watch(function() {
        return ctrl.data;
      }, function(newVal) {
        // d3 code part
      });

      socketio.on(event, function(newdata) {
        ctrl.data.push(newdata);
        // redraw chart
      });
    }
  };
});
```

In the above d3 code part, I refer to *http://bl.ocks.org/gniemetz/4618602*. The main code is almost the same and the chart is displayed well.

Now I want to use socket.io to update the chart via code

```
socketio.on(event, function(newdata) {
  ctrl.data.push(newdata);
  // redraw chart
});
```

but do not know how to redraw the chart efficiently with the updated 'ctrl.data'. I know in Morris.js, we could do this by '.setData(ctrl.data)' method, but do not know how to update in d3. Any idea?

ps: I tried to copy/paste the d3 code above to this place, but there was always an error said: "TypeError: t.slice is not a function"

Thanks,

Comment: I think calling `myD3Selection.data(newdata)` will trigger d3's insert/update/remove handlers

Comment: wondering what is myD3Selection?thanks, @Plato

Comment: a d3 selection is zero or more DOM elements, usually identified with css like `li.myDataBoundItems`. d3 maps one item from the data array onto each of the elements in the selection. this lets your DOM update reactively when you change the data. @mbostock has a detailed explanation here http://bost.ocks.org/mike/selection/

Comment: @Plato, while that's correct, it's only a piece of what's needed. See the Fiddle in my answer for more info.

Comment: @Plato yeah, the website helps. I think it is also a promising solution, let me try it later. Thank you for your help, plato.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**The quick and dirty way:**  every time you have an update, empty the `<div>` and redraw the entire graph.

**The more elegant way:**  write your own `update` function to add new data.  This is by far the most visually appealing way, since the graph will actually be animated.  D3 is well built for this sort of thing, so its by no means a stretch of its capabilities.  This will take a bit longer, but usually provides a much more pleasing experience, as seen on some of the graphs in D3's gallery (examples: http://square.github.io/crossfilter/ , http://bl.ocks.org/NPashaP/96447623ef4d342ee09b) Here's how I would do it using your desired graph:

- Keep your code the same
- Add an update function, say named `Update()`, that's called in the `socketio.on(...)` section where you commented `// redraw chart`
- `Update()` will then redefine all D3 variables and animate the change

`Update()` will essentially do the above bullet by performing a subset of the steps used in creating the graph from scratch.  Here's an overview of what it'll do:  rescale both the x and y axes, graphically update the axes, translate the original points and lines to their new positions on new axes, add new points, and add any lines it may need to complete the graph

I'm working on a jsFiddle for you with a working `Update` to demo the above and, hopefully, implementing it in your code will be simple.  I'll edit this post when its done, but I wanted to give you the "quick" answer while I work on it in an attempt to help you meanwhile.  If you want some reading meanwhile, check out 
http://blog.visual.ly/creating-animations-and-transitions-with-d3-js/

---

**UPDATE**

https://jsfiddle.net/npzjLng9/2/.  I took the example you provided and had to modify the data to be loaded to be local, not from a text file; however, it is in the same format, and also a lot less entries for readability.  Other than that, I did not make any changes to the example.  Here's what I added: scroll down and find the last function, `Update`.  Here is where the update and animation happens.  Notice the flow of the function:

1. "update" the data as if your `socket.io` was the one who received it and then appended it to the dataset.
2. Redefine the axes
3. Redefine the points and paths
4. Specify a transition duration (feel free to play with whatever number suits you)
5. Actually update and animate changes on the plot

I added a button to simulate a `socket.io` receiving event.

For your application, ignore the `data.push` and `console.log` in the `Update()` function and I think that's all you'd need -- other than pointing the data to your `ctrl.data` array and running the `Update()` function in your `socketio.on(...)`, of course.

The same basic outline applies to animating/updating most graphs.

I hope this helps you!

Comment: thank you very much, @mjdiaz89 I am trying as well following your guide, looking forward to your jsFiddle

Comment: I uploaded the fiddle (edited post above). Take a look and let me know if you have any questions. Enjoy!

Comment: Excellent reply, it helps a lot. But I think it will still take me some more time to digest you code. Anyway, thank you for your great help. @mjdiaz89

Comment: I wanna use socketio to update data, so I copy and paste your update function body and put it into socketio.on callback function like this, http://jsfiddle.net/lszhou/zLeyv0q2/  But I got the error "Error: Invalid value for <path> attribute", I guess it has something to do with variable scope, please advise. @Manuel J. Diaz

Comment: Does that work?  I think you would have a variable scope issue, no?  The Fiddle I provided works because all the variable declarations at the root of the script are also in scope inside the `Update()` function, so then D3 is able to redefine them and update the graph accordingly.

Comment: yes, that's why I put the socketio.on function in the `function(newVal){...}`, there is no "variable undefined" error, the only error provided is a series of "Error: Invalid value for <path> attribute, d="MNaN,0.003336358....", no idea why, any idea about that? thanks. @Manuel J. Diaz

Comment: Yea, I was just asking to make sure, but sounds like you took care of that the correct way :-)  Hmm... the data array is correct? It sounds like the `main.selectAll(...)` portion is the one throwing the errors, yes?  Are the `main.selectAll(...)` grabbing the right SVG element, i.e. is the selector correct?

Comment: yes, totally right, `main.selectAll(...)` codes are the reason, when I delete them (the last several lines), then no errors any more. How could I check if it is grabbing the right SVG elem? @Manuel J. Diaz

Comment: Place in a `console.log(main.selectAll(...))` statement in the line above each `main.selectAll(...)` call and check out if they are the right elements.  For example `console.log(main.selectAll("path.line.line0"))`.  Also, any behavior seen on the graph, or just console errors?

Comment: when I put the console statement there, it prints `[Array[1], select: function, selectAll: function, attr: function, classed: function, style: function…]`. After push the new data, the chart is shown correctly by refreshing. But at the point of time of pushing, these errors show up. One thing I notice is when I change `.datum(data)` to be `.data(data)`, the above errors disappear and the errors left are series of `Error: Invalid value for <circle> attribute transform="translate(NaN,203.63513493121962)"` @Manuel J. Diaz

Comment: after pushing the newdata, the chart does not show up until I refresh the webpage. @Manuel J. Diaz

Comment: It's probably something small that's causing the error.  Is there anyway you can provide a full-working Fiddle or Plunker?  Also, not that this is the source of the error, but as a side note, in the original Fiddle I provided, I had a code block pasted twice in two different locations.  I updated the post to include the revised Fiddle.

Comment: I am sorry that I can not provide the full version code since it is a private project. But anyway, I appreciate your patience. Let me stick to it for some more time. Good luck with me, haha@Manuel J. Diaz

Comment: I get it done. The bug has nothing to do with `main.selectAll(...)`, sorry for the confusing. it is because of the time format. In your code, you use `new Date(data[data.length-1].Uhrzeit.getTime() + 60000)`, however my new data passed by socketio is of original format, like `05:45`. The solution is also quite straightforward, add `newdata.Uhrzeit = parseDate(newdata.Uhrzeit);` to change the format then push it. Then it is done. Thank you, Manuel. @Manuel J. Diaz

Comment: Ahh, yeah, that would do it, but I'm glad to hear it's all working! You're very welcome -- enjoy!